# Bytes are unaccounted for after memory-mapping and sorting a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, computer-science

I have a file which consists of 69-byte messages. No EOL characters- just message after message. The total number of bytes in the file is exactly 11,465,930,307, which is (11,465,930,307/69) = 166,172,903 messages.

My program memory-maps the file in to a byte array, looks at each 69-byte message and extracts the timestamp. I keep track of which message number I am on and then the timestamp and the message number go in a `RowDetails` object, which goes in a `std::vector<RowDetails>` called `to_sort`, so that I can effectively sort the whole file by timestamp.

```
std::cout << "Sorting....." << to_sort.size() << " rows..." << std::endl;
std::sort(std::begin(to_sort), std::end(to_sort));
```

However, then I create a new file which is sorted:

```
unsigned long long total_bytes=0;
unsigned long long total_rows=0;

ofstream a_file("D:\\sorted_all");

std::cout << "Outputting " << to_sort.size() << " rows..." << std::endl;
std::cout << "Outputting " << (to_sort.size()*69) << " bytes..." << std::endl;

for(RowDetails rd : to_sort){
    for(unsigned long long i = rd.msg_number*69; i<(rd.msg_number*69)+69; i++){
        a_file << current_bytes[i];
        total_bytes++;
    }
    total_rows++;
}

std::cout << "Vector rows: "<< total_rows <<std::endl;
std::cout << "Bytes: " << total_bytes <<std::endl;
```

My output:

```
No. of total bytes (before memory-mapping file): 11,465,930,307         CORRECT
Sorting....... 166,172,903 rows         CORRECT
Outputting 166,172,903 rows....         CORRECT
Outputting 11,465,930,307 bytes         CORRECT
Vector rows: 166,172,903                CORRECT
Bytes: 11,465,930,169                   ERROR, THIS SHOULD BE 307, not 169
```

How can I process the correct number of rows, but my counter, counting total bytes is wrong??

When looking at the output file in Windows 7 explorer it says size: 11,503,248,366 bytes, even though the original input file (which I memory-mapped) said the correct 11,465,930,307.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess based on the snippet of code you have provided, but I'm willing to bet that `rd.msg_number` is a 32-bit type. It seems likely that `rd.msg_number*69` would then sometimes overflow its 32-bit result, causing incorrect calculations in the inner loop bounds. I would do something like the following:

```
for(RowDetails rd : to_sort){
    long long msg_offset = (long long)rd.msg_number * 69;
    for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < 69; i++){
        a_file << current_bytes[msg_offset+i];
        total_bytes++;
    }
    total_rows++;
}
```

For the incorrect output file size, the reason is your `a_file` output file is opened in the default *text* mode, instead of *binary* mode. In text mode, stdio will do EOL conversion which you aren't going to want. So change the file open statement to:

```
ofstream a_file("d:\\sorted_all", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Comment: Agreed.  There appear to be two extra records in the output: 11,465,930,307 - 11,465,930,307 = 138; 138 = 69 * 2.

Comment: Ok it solved the problem whereby my total byte counter is now correct (thanks for that). However, the size of the output file in Windows is 11,502,960,296 bytes, versus the input file: 11,465,930,307 bytes. Is this because the ofstream inserts data??

Comment: I see you're not opening your output file in binary mode. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Its now 11,465,928,704 bytes

Comment: Output file now 11,465,928,704 bytes in size

Comment: This number is evenly divisible by 4096.  4K blocks maybe?

Comment: @user997112: Perhaps you could simply look at the contents of the output file (use your favourite hex editor) to see what the difference is. It's getting harder for us to guess what might be wrong simply based on the resulting file size.